# Prove that $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{1}{(x+2y)^2}} \geq\frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}$ for $x, y, z > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, substitution, uvw

> Let $x,y,z>0$. Prove that
> $$\frac{1}{(x+2y)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+2z)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+2x)^2} \geq\frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}.$$

I tried to apply Cauchy - Schwarz's inequality but I couldn't prove this inequality!

Comment: By reciprocating the whole inequality and apply AM-HM, I arrive at $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq xy+yz+zx$. You sure there is no condition missing?

Comment: I'm sure. Only 1 condition: $x,y,z>0$

Comment: At least I tried ;P

Comment: try $$a=0.01,b=100,c=0.001$$

Comment: your inequality is not true! try $$a=\frac{1}{100},b=100,c=\frac{1}{1000}$$

Comment: Do you need this inequality in some larger context and it currently obstructs your advance? Or is it for practice in inequalities−and one should possibly add the (contest-math) tag. Just curious where it does come from ...

Comment: @Hanno This inequality is similar to Iran 1996 $(ab+ca+bc)\left(\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}\right)\geq\frac{9}{4}$, which is Ji Chen's inequality.

Comment: This inequality is similar to Iran MO 1996.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a=x+2y,b=y+2z,c=z+2x \implies x=\dfrac{a-2b+4c}{9},y=\dfrac{b-2c+4a}{9},z=\dfrac{c-2a+4b}{9}$

the inequality become:

$\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2} \ge \dfrac{27}{5(ab+bc+ac)-2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$

now use UVW method:

$3u=a+b+c,3v^2=ab+bc+ac,w^3=abc \implies u\ge v\ge w$

$\iff \dfrac{(3v^2)^2-6uw^3}{w^6}\ge \dfrac{3}{3v^2-2u^2} \iff w^6+2u(3v^2-2u^2)w^3-3v^4(3v^2-u^2) \le 0$

let $w^3=x,f(x)=x^2+2u(3v^2-2u^2)x-3v^4(3v^2-2u^2)$

$2u(3v^2-2u^2) \ge 0 $

$f_{max}(x)=f(w^3|w=v)=f(v^3)$, when $w=v \implies u=v=w \implies f(v^3)=0 \implies f(x) \le 0 $

when $u=v=w \implies a=b=c \implies x=y=z$

QED.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Nice solution! :D

Comment: But why $2u(3v^2-2u^2)\ge 0$? I think it's wrong?

Comment: because $27(xy+yz+xz)=5(ab+bc+ac)-2(a^2+b^2+c^2)>0$

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I've seen ! :D You are welcome! :D

Answer (score 3):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Hence, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^5b+4a^4c-12a^4b^2+12a^4c^2+5a^3b^3+8a^4bc-19a^3b^2c+5a^3c^2b-7a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^5b+4a^4c+5a^3b^3+8a^4bc-7a^3b^2c-7a^3c^2b-7a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq12\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2-a^4c^2+a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b)$$  or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^5b+4a^4c+5a^3b^3+8a^4bc-7a^3b^2c-7a^3c^2b-7a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq12(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc).$$
Since by Schur $3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b^3-a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^5b+4a^4c+2a^3b^3+8a^4bc-4a^3b^2c-4a^3c^2b-10a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq12(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^5b+2a^4c+a^3b^3+4a^4bc-2a^3b^2c-2a^3c^2b-5a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq6(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$18u^4v^2-24u^2v^4+5v^6+2u^3w^3-uv^2w^3\geq2(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)uv^2$$ 
and since $18u^4v^2-24u^2v^4+5v^6+2u^3w^3-uv^2w^3\geq0$, it's enough to prove that
$$\left(18u^4v^2-24u^2v^4+5v^6+2u^3w^3-uv^2w^3\right)^2\geq4(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2u^2v^4$$ or
$$\left(18u^4v^2-24u^2v^4+5v^6+2u^3w^3-uv^2w^3\right)^2\geq108(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)u^2v^4$$ or
$$(4u^4-4u^2v^2+109v^4)u^2w^6+2uv^2(36u^6+150u^4v^2-290u^2v^4-5v^6)w^3+$$
$$+(324u^8-864u^6v^2+432u^4v^4+192u^2v^6+25v^8)v^4\geq0.$$
Since $324t^4-864t^3+432t^2+192t+25>0$, it's remains to prove that
$$t(36t^3+150t^2-290t-5)^2-t(4t^2-4t+109)(324t^4-864t^3+432t^2+192t+25)\leq0$$ or
$$t(t-1)^2(144t^3-72t^2-216t-25)\leq0,$$ where $t\geq1$ and $36t^3+150t^2-290t-5<0$.

Let $p(t)=36t^3+150t^2-290t-5$ and $q(t)=144t^3-72t^2-216t-25$.

By Descartes $p$ has an unique positive root $x_1$ and $q$ has an unique positive root $x_2$.

But $p(1.5)=19>0$ and $q(1.5)=-25<0$, which says that $q(x)<0$ for all $1\leq x\leq x_1$

and we are done!

Comment: How did you proved the inequality when it has counterexample

Comment: @didgogns  Try to check the counterexample.

Comment: Now I checked that Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's 'counterexample' is not counterexample. Why did I thought so last time? :(

Comment: @didgogns I saw it hour ago, but I wished to prove this inequality. Now you can check my proof. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume $z=min\{x,y,z\}$, we prove two inequalities
$$$$1. $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{(2x+y)^2} \geqslant \frac{1}{9xy}+\frac{8}{9(x+z)(y+z)}$$
which is true by expanding
$$$$2.$$\frac{1}{9xy}+\frac{8}{9(x+z)(y+z)} \geqslant \frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}$$
which is equivalent to $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \geqslant 8xyz$

Answer (score 2):

Also we can make the following.

From my previous post we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^5b+4a^4c-12a^4b^2+12a^4c^2+5a^3b^3+8a^4bc-19a^3b^2c+5a^3c^2b-7a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$6\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2-b^2-2ab+2ac)^2+\sum_{sym}(2a^5b-a^3b^3-4a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-7a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$
which is obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative proof** without full expanding or uvw:

Let
$$u = \frac{1}{x + 2y}, \quad
v = \frac{1}{y + 2z}, \quad w = \frac{1}{z + 2x}.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} \\
 =\,& u^2 + v^2 + w^2 - \frac{1}{xy + yz + zx}\\
 =\,& \frac{(u-v)^2 + (v - w)^2 + (w-u)^2}{2} + uv + vw + wu - \frac{1}{xy + yz + zx}\\
 =\,& \frac{(u-v)^2 + (v - w)^2 + (w-u)^2}{2} + \frac{3(x + y + z)}{(x + 2y)(y + 2z)(z + 2x)} - \frac{1}{xy + yz + zx}\\
 =\,& \frac{(u-v)^2 + (v - w)^2 + (w-u)^2}{2}
 - \frac{(y-x)(y-z)(x-z)}{(x+2y)(y+2z)(z+2x)(xy+yz+zx)}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

WLOG, assume that $z = \min(x, y, z)$.

From (1), we only need to prove the case $y \ge x \ge z$.

If $2x \ge y + z$, from (1),
we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}
 &\ge \frac{(v - u + v - w + w - u)^2}{6} - \frac{(y-x)\cdot (y - z + x - z)^2/4}{(x+2y)(y+2z)(y+2z)xy} \tag{2}\\
 &= \frac{2(x + y - 2z)^2}{3(x + 2y)^2(y + 2z)^2} - \frac{(y-x) (x + y - 2z)^2}{4(x+2y)(y+2z)^2xy}\\
 &= \frac{(x + y - 2z)^2}{(x+2y)(y+2z)^2}
 \left(\frac{2}{3(x + 2y)} - \frac{y-x}{4xy}\right)\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where in (2) we use $(u-v)^2 + (v - w)^2 + (w-u)^2
\ge (v-u + v - w + w - u)^2 /3$, and
$(y - z)(x - z) \le (y - z + x - z)^2/4$, and $z + 2x \ge y + 2z$,
and $xy + yz + zx \ge xy$;
and the last inequality follows from
$\frac{2}{3(x + 2y)} - \frac{y-x}{4xy}
\ge \frac{2}{3(x + 4x)} - \frac{y-x}{4xy} = \frac{15x  -7y}{60xy} \ge 0$.

If $2x < y + z$, from (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}
 &\ge \frac{(v - u + w - v + w - u)^2}{6} - \frac{(x-z)(2y - x - z)^2/4}{(x+2y)(z+2x)(z+2x)xy} \tag{3}\\
 &= \frac{2(2y - x - z)^2}{(x+2y)^2(z+2x)^2} - \frac{(x-z)(2y - x - z)^2}{4(x+2y)(z+2x)^2xy}\\
 &= \frac{(2y - x - z)^2}{(x + 2y)(z + 2x)^2}
 \left(\frac{2}{3(x + 2y)} - \frac{x - z}{4xy}\right)\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where in (3) we use
$(u-v)^2 + (v-w)^2 + (w-u)^2 \ge (v - u + w - v + w - u)^2/3$, and $(y - x)(y - z) \le (y - x + y - z)^2/4$,
and $y+2z \ge z + 2x$, and $xy + yz + zx \ge xy$;
and the last inequality follows from
$\frac{2}{3(x + 2y)} - \frac{x - z}{4xy} = \frac{2xy + 3zx + 6yz - 3x^2}{12(x+2y)xy} \ge 0
$ (using $2xy + 2zx = 2x(y + z) \ge 2x \cdot 2x = 4x^2$).

We are done.