# Starting an inequality family: How far can we go?

Tags: inequality

Consider the inequality
$$(ab+bc+ca)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{(ka+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(kb+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(kc+a)^2}\right)\,\ge\,\frac{9}{(k+1)^2}\tag{"Case $k$"}$$
with variables $\,a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}\,$ and parameter $\,k\in\mathbb{R}$.

(At least) the two instances with $\,k=1\,$ and
[$\,k=2\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906972/316749)
have yet found their home at math.SE being answered in the positive. The case $\,k=1\,$ is entitled 
['Hard inequality'](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/959688/316749) (aka "Iran 1996" amongst insiders I guess), cf the comments there containing further references.

**My question:** *For which other values of the parameter $k$ does the inequality* "Case $k$" *hold true?*

Please note that "Case $k$" is invariant under replacing $\,k\mapsto \frac{1}{k}\,$ and simultaneously switching any two out of the three variables.
So I'd expect that any $\,k>0\,$ yields a valid statement. To 'complete the proof job' it would suffice if a reduction from $\,k>1\,$to $\,k=1\,$ can be achieved.

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828773/ab-bc-ca-left-frac-1a-pba-qb-frac-1b-pcb-qc/3829012#3829012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof in the parameter range $\,k\geqslant 0\,$ is proposed which relies on the known case $k=1$.

It encompasses the following steps, hereby submitted to the community's critical eye:

- Variable transformation, to simplify the subsequent
- clearing of denominators.
- Scaling the inequality and
- arguing that its $k=1$ instance yields a lower bound for other values of $k$.
- Limit case $k\to 0$

Let's send $\:a,b,c\:$ to the new variables $\:u,v,w\:$ via
$$\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\\ w\end{pmatrix}\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}k&1&0\\0&k&1\\1&0&k\end{pmatrix}\,
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that $\,u+v+w=(k+1)(a+b+c)$, and especially
$$\begin{matrix}
\sum_\text{cyc}uv & = & \left(k^2+k+1\right)\sum_\text{cyc}ab & +
 & k\:\sum_\text{cyc}a^2 \\[1.5ex]
\sum_\text{cyc}u^2 & = & 2k\:\sum_\text{cyc}ab &
 + & \left(k^2+1\right)\sum_\text{cyc}a^2\,.
\end{matrix}$$
Assume $\,k>0\,$ and combine the preceding two identities to obtain
$$
\left(k+\frac 1 k +1\right)(k+1)^2\sum_\text{cyc}ab\;=\;
\left(k+\frac 1 k\right)\sum_\text{cyc}uv -\sum_\text{cyc}u^2\,.
$$
This is used when multiplying ("Case $k$"), the given inequality, with $\,(k+\frac 1 k -1)(k+1)^2\,u^2v^2w^2$, and after clearing the RHS let
$$
g(k,u,v,w)\;:=\;\left[\left(k+\frac 1 k\right)\sum_\text{cyc}uv -\sum_\text{cyc}u^2 \right]
\cdot\sum_\text{cyc}u^2v^2\; -\;9\left(k+\frac 1 k -1\right)u^2v^2w^2\,.
$$
Note that the freedom to scale the function $g$ has been exploited such that the second "$\sum$" in the brackets does not depend on $k\;\implies$ will drop out upon differentiation w.r.to $k$.

*It has to be shown that* $\,g(k,u,v,w)\geq 0\;\:\forall\, k,u,v,w>0\,$.

This is accomplished by one-variable analysis in $k$ with $\,u,v,w\,$ fixed.
$g$ enjoys the invariance property $\,g(1/k,\ldots)=g(k,\ldots)\,$ implying
$\,\frac 1kg_k\big(\frac 1k,\ldots\big)=-k\,g_k(k,\ldots)\,$ where $g_k\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial k}g$. In particular $\,g_k(1,\ldots)=0\,$. Thus the known case $\,g(1,\ldots)\geqslant0\,$ is a bound for $\,g(k,\ldots)\,$, but we badly need $\,g_k(k,\ldots)\geqslant0\,$ for $\,k\geqslant 1\,$ to conclude it's a *lower* bound!

Now
$$
g_k(k,u,v,w)\;=\;\left(1-\frac 1{k^2}\right)
\left[\left(\sum_\text{cyc}uv\right)\left(\sum_\text{cyc}u^2v^2\right)\; -\;9u^2v^2w^2\right]
$$
and separation of terms involving all three variables from those containing two and distributing the multiples of $\,u^2v^2w^2\,$ accordingly leads to
$$
=\;\left(1-\frac 1{k^2}\right)
\left[uvw\sum_\text{cyc}u(v-w)^2\; +\;\frac{uv+vw+wu}{2} 
\sum_\text{cyc}u^2(v-w)^2\right]\,.
$$
**Bingo**, *coz the bracket is a sum of squares with positive coefficients.* This completes the $\,k>0\,$ case.

Since the inequality is built on "$\le$" (and not "$<$") the case "$k=0$" holds by continuity too, just send $k$ to $0\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following my delirium will help.

It's enough to prove our inequality for all $k\geq1$.

A full expending gives $f(k)\geq0$, where
$$f(k)=\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)k^6+$$
$$+2\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)k^5+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c-9a^4b^2+4a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-22a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)k^4+$$
$$+2\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c+a^4b^2+a^4c^2-8a^3b^3-6a^4bc+8a^3b^2c+8a^3c^2b-6a^2b^2c^2)k^3+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c+4a^4b^2-9a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc-22a^3b^2c+10a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)k^2+$$
$$+2\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc+3a^3b^2c-7a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)k+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2).$$
We'll prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$ 
Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{ab}{c^2}+\frac{a^2}{bc}-\frac{7a}{c}+\frac{3a}{b}+1\right)\geq0.$$
Let $\frac{a}{b}=x$, $\frac{b}{c}=y$ and $\frac{c}{a}=z$.

Hence, $xyz=1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2+x^2y+x^2z-7xy+3x+1)\geq0.$$
Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$(9u^2-6v^2)w+9uv^2-3w^3-21v^2w+9uw^2+3w^3\geq0$$ 
or $g(v^2)\geq0$, where
$$g(v^2)=(u-3w)v^2+u^2w+uw^2.$$
We see that $g$ is a linear function, which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extremal value of $v^2$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$ and $z=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

We need to prove that 
$$(x-1)^2(2x^5-x^4+2x^3+10x^2+4x+1)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Hence, 
$$f''''(k)=360\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)k^2+$$
$$+240\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)k+$$
$$+24\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c-9a^4b^2+4a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-22a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq360\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)+$$
$$+240\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)+$$
$$+24\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c-9a^4b^2+4a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-22a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=24\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c+4a^4b^2+a^4c^2+27a^3b^3+15a^4bc-45a^3b^2c+23a^3c^2b-27a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Hence,
$$f'''(k)=120\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)k^3+$$
$$+120\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)k^2+$$
$$+24\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c-9a^4b^2+4a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-22a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)k+$$
$$+12\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c+a^4b^2+a^4c^2-8a^3b^3-6a^4bc+8a^3b^2c+8a^3c^2b-6a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq120\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^3b^2c+a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)+$$
$$+120\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc-7a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)+$$
$$+24\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c-9a^4b^2+4a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+5a^4bc+10a^3b^2c-22a^3c^2b+8a^2b^2c^2)+$$
$$+12\sum_{cyc}(a^5b+a^5c+a^4b^2+a^4c^2-8a^3b^3-6a^4bc+8a^3b^2c+8a^3c^2b-6a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$12\sum_{cyc}(3a^5b+3a^5c-17a^4b^2+19a^4c^2+16a^3b^3+14a^4bc-32a^3b^2c+4a^3c^2b-10a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$12\sum_{cyc}(3a^5b+3a^5c-17a^4b^2+19a^4c^2+14a^3b^3+14a^4bc-30a^3b^2c+4a^3c^2b-10a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=12\sum_{cyc}(3x^3y+3x^3z-17x^2y^2+19x^2+14x^2y+14x^2z-30xy+4x-10),$$
which can be negative!

Comment: What is the conclusion?  $f'''(k)$ may take some negative values, but that does not decide whether $f(k)$ can be negative.

Comment: @user254665 Sometimes it helps. By the way, I think I see something!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If the "something" is worthwhile to be shared can only be estimated if you share it, don’t you?

Comment: @Hanno No! My "something" it's just nothing. I am sorry.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  All good ;-) U needn't be sorry. Btw, had an idea how to show the general case when assuming "Iran 1996", i.e. case $k=1$. Hope to get it written down soon.

Answer (score 0):

**"Case k=0"**
Just another brick in the wall, not a comprehensive answer. It is shown that the inequality holds true for the parameter value $k=0$.

After clearing denominators we face the expression
$$(ab+bc+ca)\left[\sum_\text{cyc}a^2b^2\right]\;-\;9a^2b^2c^2$$
to be transformed in a sum of squares with positive prefactors.

In the first summand separate terms involving all three variables from those containing two, and spread the multiples of $a^2b^2c^2$ accordingly
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 & =\quad & abc\left[\sum_\text{cyc}\left(b^2c+bc^2\right)-6abc\right]\;+\;\underbrace{\sum_\text{cyc}a^3b^3 - 3a^2b^2c^2}_\text{is AM-GM} \\[3ex]
 & =\quad & abc\sum_\text{cyc}a(b-c)^2\:
 +\:\frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}\,\sum_\text{cyc}a^2(b-c)^2
\end{eqnarray}$$
To the underbraced summand the identity
$r^3+s^3+t^3-3rst=\frac 12(r+s+t)\sum_\text{cyc}(r-s)^2$
with $ab,bc,ca\,$ inserted has been applied.