# $(ab + bc + ca) \left(\frac {1}{(a + pb)(a + qb)} + \frac {1}{(b + pc)(b + qc)} + \frac{1}{(c + pa)(c + qa)}\right)\ge \frac {9}{(p + 1)(q + 1)}$

Tags: inequality, uvw

One of my friends showed me this inequality.
$$(ab + bc + ca)  \left(\frac {1}{(a + pb)(a + qb)} + \frac {1}{(b + pc)(b + qc)} + \frac{1}{(c + pa)(c + qa)}\right)\ge \frac {9}{(p + 1)(q + 1)}$$ for every positive numbers $a, b, c, p$ and $q.$
My first idea was to use Bergstrom's Inequality, so I would have $$\frac {1}{(a + pb)(a + qb)} + \frac {1}{(b + pc)(b + qc)} + \frac{1}{(c + pa)(c + qa)} \ge \frac {9}{(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2) (pq + 1) + pq (ab + bc + ca)} \ge \frac {9}{(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)(pq + p + q + 1)} = \frac {9}{(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)(p + 1)(q + 1)},$$ but in the end we get to $$\frac {ab + bc + ca}{a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2} \ge 1,$$ which is obviously false.

I am eager to hear your advice.

Comment: [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h471436p2639224).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That particular solution at AOPS seems wrong.  Disregarding obvious typos in the inequality signs, it still cannot hold as $a^2+b^2+c^2\geqslant ab+bc+ca$ which reverses an intermediate step.

Comment: Thanks @Macavity. I just tried an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(ab%20%2B%20bc%20%2B%20ca)%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7B(a%20%2B%20pb)(a%20%2B%20qb)%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7B(b%20%2B%20pc)(b%20%2B%20qc)%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(c%20%2B%20pa)(c%20%2B%20qa)%7D%5Cright)%5Cge%20%5Cfrac%20%7B9%7D%7B(p%20%2B%201)(q%20%2B%201)%7D%24&p=1), but obviously didn't check. Anyway, it is surely beneficial to keep the link to the AOPS version in case somebody posts there.

Comment: It might actually be a good idea to discuss the potential problems related to duplication of material from AOPS. But that should take place in meta.

Comment: I commented only to ensure no one settles for that wrong AOPS answer.  Agreed that a quick search on AOPS has value in avoiding duplications for at least contest type problems like inequalities.

Comment: @andu eu   It's  unsolved problem. Even for $p=q=2$ it's not so easy. For $p=q=1$ it's the Ji Chen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The AM-GM:
$\dfrac{(q+1)(a+pb)+(p+1)(a+qb)}2 \geqslant \sqrt{(p+1)(q+1)(a+pb)(a+qb)}$
$$\implies \frac1{(a+pb)(a+qb)}\geqslant \frac{4(p+1)(q+1)}{[(q+1)(a+pb)+(p+1)(a+qb)]^2}=\frac{4(p+1)(q+1)}{[(p+q+2)a+(2pq+p+q)b]^2}$$
Defining $k$ using $2pq+p+q=k(p+q+2)$, the above can be rewritten as
$$\frac1{(a+pb)(a+qb)}\geqslant \frac{4(p+1)(q+1)}{(p+q+2)^2(a+kb)^2}$$

Using this, it is enough to show that (with $\sum$ denoting cyclic sums):
$$\left(\sum ab\right)\cdot \sum \frac1{\left(a+kb \right)^2} \geqslant \frac{9(p+q+2)^2}{4(p+1)^2(q+1)^2} = \frac9{(k+1)^2} \tag{1}$$

We can make this symmetric using the substitution $x = a+kb, y = b+kc, z = c + ka$, to instead prove:
$$\sum \frac1{x^2}\geqslant \frac{9(k^2-k+1)}{(k^2+1)\sum xy - k\sum x^2}$$

For this, it may be expedient to use the so called "*uvw*" method - let $3u = \sum x, 3v^2=\sum xy, w^3=xyz$, so that $u\geqslant v\geqslant w$.    Note as the RHS is positive, we also have $(k^2+1)\sum xy > k\sum x^2 \implies (k+1)^2v^2>3ku^2$.  Now the inequality is
$$\frac{(3v^2)^2-6uw^3}{w^6}\geqslant \frac{3(k^2-k+1)}{(k+1)^2v^2-3ku^2}$$
$$(k^2-k+1)w^6 +2u[(k+1)^2v^2-3ku^2]w^3-3v^4[(k+1)^2v^2-3ku^2]\leqslant 0$$

As the LHS is a quadratic in $w^3$ with both leading coefficients positive, it is maximised when $w$ attains its maximum, viz. $w=v$, which implies $w=v=u \implies x=y=z \implies a=b=c$, hence it is enough to check inequality $(1)$ for this case, which is obviously true.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to give a reason?

Comment: (I did not downvote you.)  One may be careful: There are some constraints on $x, y, z$ from $x = a + kb, y=b+kc, z = c + ka$ since $a, b, c > 0$. See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1463149p12461943

Comment: I think that you do not make it symmetric since the constraints are not symmetric. I put an example for which the uvw method may not work as usual. See #30 in the link above. Also see #32, KaiRain's explanation.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for linking the AOPS thread.  I see a specific counter example for $uvw$ application in a similar case, which however involves minimisation of $w^3$, which apparently fails due to the added constraints disallowing the minimum otherwise reachable.  In the post above I am actually not using the minima, and it seems $v=w$ is perfectly allowable here so the maximum in the larger set should prevail even if more constraints are introduced (which may be restricting the minimum of the interval for $w^3$).  However will study that e.g. more to see what's happening before reverting.

Comment: On your second comment on symmetry, I am not worried.  For e.g. to prove the cyclic $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geqslant 3abc$, I see absolutely no reason why we can't substitute $x^3=a^2b, y^3=b^2c, z^3=c^2a$ to get the symmetric $x^3+y^3+z^3\geqslant 3xyz$ to prove instead.  The first comment however deserves more study, will revert in a few hours when I have a bit more time.

Comment: Yes, I think that we must add something different from the usual uvw method since the uvw method fails sometimes (see #30 in the link above).

Comment: @RobertZ  Do you mean Macavity's answer should be accepted? I think that Macavity's answer is incorrect. Hope more users come here to discuss whether or not Macavity's answer is correct.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for pointing out.